# I want to run a new page on my website after the registration is finish

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Wen I finish (successfully) the new user registration I want to change the current page in a new notification page from my code behind.
For this purpose I use a javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Tag;
    function notifyscript(TagName) {
        tag = TagName;
        var myTag = document.getElementById(tag);
        myTag.click();

    }
```

in order to call:

```
<a id="notify" href="http://localhost/Pages/Account/Notification.aspx"  target="_parent"/>
```

But it trow me an error when I run this locally.
`500 (HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The call fails LoadLibraryEx στο φίλτρο ISAPI "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\aspnet_filter.dll"`
 When I run this in the web doing nothing.
Is there someone who knows how to do this action?
I mean to open a new page when the code behind ends the registration.

Comment: That is for the person which down vote my question. Before you do anything in your life try to use your mind it will helps. And if you know the answer then... here is best place to say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code on Code Behind:

```
string url="www.google.com";
string msg = "<script type='text/javascript'>" +
                   " $(document).ready(function(){ " +
                   " window.location.href='" + url + "';" +
                   " });" +
               "</script>";
 page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(page.GetType(), "myURL", msg);
```

Comment: At first din't want to see the `$` I delete it and run it again. And throws me an error `JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'ready'`

Comment: Please add jquery library https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Dear your solution was excellent, and works just fine... Thank you very much.